# Copy generated folder from one job to another in Hudson/Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have two jobs in my Hudson configuration. Let's call them A and B.

Job A was created specifically to generate a folder **application_home**. This folder is a ready-to-be-used-in-installations-application-home-folder.

Job B is the "pack-all-together-for-installation-job". It needs to copy the **application_home** generated by job A to generate the installer. My problem is that after some investigation, I was not able to do this in a simple way.

I could use shell script, but then I would need to know job A path plus where its workspace is to get *application*_ *home* folder.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

**EDIT**

I know [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). The problem is that it only copies artifacts. I need to copy the folder *application*_ *home* as it is, because it's already in the structure to be used in the installer. If there's a way to use this plugin to copy only the folder, I haven't found it.

**EDIT 2. Answer:**

Ok, you can do it using [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). You need to

- Set its configuration to *"copy from WORKSPACE of latest completed build"*.
- Set *Artifacts to copy* option the folder like this: target/application_home/**
- Set *Target directory* to where you want to somethine like: installation_bundle_folder/application_home.

and it's done :)

Comment: Most probably users will not expect answer inside your question, you can answer your own question BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

Then you could add a build step to "pack-all-together-for-installation-job" that would copy `application_home` to the packaging directory. There is an option to only include the latest stable build of Project A.

---

Another alternative is to have a post-build step for a successful *Project A* build that scripts the copy of the `application_home` over to where *Project B* will use it. You can use the `WORKSPACE` environment variable to get the absolute location. (See [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) for a list of environmental variables).

Comment: I actually tryied Copy Artifact Plugin, but it seems to be able to copy only maven artifacts. `jar`s per say. My application_home is inside the "target" folder of one of the submodules of the project of job A. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: @RalfHoppen another idea is to script it, though I'd suggest a "push" workflow over a "pull".

Comment: Found a way using Copy Artifact. I needed to check "copy from WORKSPACE from latest succesful build" and set the path to the application_home. :)